# У кого еще не загружается новая версия flutter?

Tags: flutter

Последнее время заметил массу проблем с flutter. В одном случае при установке пакета выводит ошибку Authentication error (403), в другом при компиляции тоже происходят вещи ранее мне неизвестные. При чем раньше все решения находил очень быстро, так разработчик я начинающий - все мои косяки уже были разобраны годами раньше, сейчас уже две недели бодаюсь, а flutter выдает все новые и новые сюрпризы.  Наконец зашел на flutter.dev чтобы обновить версию, а новый релиз не отображается и не скачивается, только после смены ip. Тут я подумал, может это очередные санкции от Google, кто еще сталкивался с такой проблемой?

Comment: Тут нужно смотреть куда обращается и какие конкретно ошибки. `Authentication error` - куда то не может подключится из за того что неверный логин/пароль

Answer (score 0):

На данный момент вопрос можно закрыть. Все оказалось банально просто - санкции. Новые версии для скачивания не отображаются для жителей ЛДНР и Крыма. В связи с этим понятны остальные глюки и проблем там где быть не должны и не было раньше. Ждем импортозамещение))